# Не считывается структура из файла на си

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

У меня в файле данные структуры, которые нужно считать, но программа считает бред какой то.
Код:

```
        rewind(f);
        fscanf(f, "%d", &a);
        printf("Schitalos: %d\n", a);
        N = n + a-1;
        cataloges = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {

            fseek(f,i * sizeof(struct catalog), 0);
            fscanf_s(f, "\"%s\"\nАвтор: %s, %d г.\nТип: %s\nШифр специальности: %d\nКоличество страниц: %d.\n", cataloges[n].name, cataloges[n].author, cataloges[n].publ_year, cataloges[n].type, cataloges[n].speciality_code, cataloges[n].pages_amount);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i <=N; i++, cataloges++) 
        {
            printf("\"%s\"\nАвтор: %s, %d г.\nТип: %s\nШифр специальности: %d\nКоличество страниц: %d.\n", cataloges->name, cataloges->author, cataloges->publ_year, cataloges->type, cataloges->speciality_code, cataloges->pages_amount);
        }
```

В консоль выводит: Schitalos: 2
"ННННээээ`B}"
Автор: , 0 г.
Тип: |>}
Шифр специальности: 0
Количество страниц: 0.
""
Автор: , 0 г.
Тип:
Шифр специальности: 0
Количество страниц: 0.

Comment: Забавно. С одной стороны вы пытаетесь устанавливать позицию чтения как если это бинарный файл, а с другой — читать как текстовый. Вы уж решите что-то одно, а то получается как в том анекдоте... Какой у вас файл?

Comment: файл текстовый, но дело не в установке позиции, потому что если rewind убрать тоже самое получится

Comment: `fseek(f,i * sizeof(struct catalog), 0);` — вы уверены, что `i`-я запись начинается именно с этого места?... Если да — почему? Если нет — зачем вы это делаете?

Comment: получается эта строка не нужна?

Comment: а ещё не известно, не являються name/author в структуре catalog просто `char*`

Comment: name и author - массивы char

Comment: Если файл текстовый — то да, читать надо одну запись за другой. Но читать правильно (например, `%s` — это чтение *одного слова*)? и с обязательной проверкой, все ли верно считано, с учетом разных возможных неприятностей — типа, оставшиеся в буфере ввода символ новой строки и т.п. Словом, я бы предпочел и писать, и читать бинарный файл.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо:)